# How to improve training time of SVM in r using caret package?

Tags: r, svm, r-caret, training-data

I am training a SVM with radial kernel on a big dataset of 244058 customers for churn prediction. I do k=5 cross validation and want to train on the basis of a custom grid.  I use parallel processing with 5 cores, and still it takes many hours to run the model and I just quit it because it takes so much time and my computer heats up. I have 4 cores CPU and 12 gb ram, so I do not think the memory or processing is the problem. I also scaled and centered the data, tried PCA and even removed near zero variance predictors and removed correlated variables. The code is shown below. Any tips? I have also tried RapidMiner instead of R, but the educational license only allows the use of 1 CPU core.

```
 doParallel::registerDoParallel(cores = 5)

 svmradialfit <- train(CHURN ~ ., data = train2scale[,-c(1,11, 13:14,16:17)],  
 method = 'svmRadial' , metric = 'AUC', maximize = TRUE, tuningGrid = expand.grid(C=100, sigma = 0.01) ,trControl = trainControl(method = 'cv', number = 5, verboseIter = TRUE, classProbs = TRUE, savePredictions = TRUE, preProcOptions = 'nzv'  ,summaryFunction = prSummary, allowParallel = TRUE) )
```

Comment: Why do you set the cores to 5 if you have 4?